# How can I position a content element in front of an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build following site.

[image]

I cant figure out how I can make the flexbox in the center of the Image. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.background {
    max-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1200px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
    <div class="background">
        <img src="../FlexBox Project/Pictures/img-mission-background.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your image shouldn't an element. It should be a background. It can be done as an image, but it's much more difficult.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image.

Comment: Yeah i tried using it as a background-image before aswell but also wasnt able to make it centered above the image unfortunatly. Thanks though.

Comment: See also https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work with following code:

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.background {
    max-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1200px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't center the content very well.

Comment: That helped in bringing the Header above the Image. Its not Centered yet unfortunatly. Also i was hoping i would be able to do it using a flexbox. But the Answer already helped thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping the div: class="header" element in a center element?

Comment: Please see [answer] and take the [tour].